# How to save a .plist file in iOS (e.g. iPhone)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new to iOS app development and I made an app which has a text field, an insert button and a table.

So, when something is entered into the text field, it is displayed on the table.

When the app enters background or terminates, it save that list as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    NSBundle *myApp = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSMutableString *fileDirectory = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[myApp bundlePath]];

    [fileDirectory appendString:@"/list.plist"];

    NSLog(@"%@", fileDirectory); //Just for refernece

    [self.viewController.tasks writeToFile:fileDirectory atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"SAVED");
}
```

and

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSBundle *myApp = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSMutableString *fileDirectory = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[myApp bundlePath]];

    [fileDirectory appendString:@"/list.plist"];

    NSLog(@"%@", fileDirectory); //Just for refernece

    [self.viewController.tasks writeToFile:fileDirectory atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"SAVED");
}
```

The file is saved.

After killing the app and opening the app again, I don't get the list back (only on my iPhone, on simulator it works fine)

Is it possible to retain the list on iPhone?

P.S: Sorry if I'm being verbose. Thank you.

Comment: why don't you use NSUserDefaults to save data of application?, if you want to use it i can share some code examples as well.

Comment: There no concept of retaining a plist file. Can you post the code which you wrote to display .plist file data in tableview (for your statement : "After killing the app and opening the app again, I don't get the list back (only on my iPhone, on simulator it works fine)").

Comment: I don't see any code to load the `.plist` file.  Also both those methods do the same thing, so the functionality should be moved to a common method.

Comment: @BharathVankireddy I think by "retain" he meant "save to disk". Not "retain" as in "memory management".

Answer (score 3):

The method `-writeToFile:atomically:` returns a `BOOL` indicating if the write operation was successful.

In your case, it will be successful on the simulator, as your are writing to your Mac's disk, which can always be done, as your process has write-privileges to your application's bundle. This is not the case on the device: because the app is code-signed the bundle is readonly, and you cannot write a file into it, so the method will return `NO`.

You should always check this value, and respond appropriately. There is also a method that takes an `NSError` pointer, so you can see why a write operation failed.

Remember that `-writeToFile:atomically:` is a synchronous operation, and it will block the thread on which it is called. In general, you want to avoid blocking the main thread, and therefore it is best to run the method on another thread (look up `dispatch_async()` and GCD documentation). In your case, your are calling it in `applicationWillTerminate:`, which is the last breath of your application and you do not want to dispatch to another thread, as it will die with the after application after `applicationWillTerminate:` returns, and most likely before that secondary thread had a chance to finish. Note, however, that `applicationWillTerminate:` might not be the best place to save state in, as time is short there, but also because this method is only called when your application will really terminate (it is not called when you press the home-button for example). Look up the documentation on the other application-lifetime methods to find out where to save your date best, you might find that you don't even need to use those methods, but saving can be done 'on th fly' while the app is running. Whatever suits your purposes.

To get a directory to which you can write, you can use for example this code:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory: NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: Also, he is not checking the return value of `-writeToFile:atomically:` and logging "SAVED" regardless.

Comment: Oops, you already mentioned it in your answer; I commented too soon.

Comment: +1: Good points about checking if save succeeded and that you can't write to the bundle. The reason is not code signing, though (it's sandboxing). Also the recommendation to save a file in the background is too generic and downright wrong in this case: At the time when `applicationWillTerminate:` is called the app is about to be pulled. The app will keep running until the method is finished, so saving synchronously is the only way to make sure the file saved before the process is killed.

Comment: Thanks, and yes you are right about dispatching while in applicationWillTerminate:. I will correct my answer for that. Chasing the bundle would cause the signature to no longer match, which is why it is readonly. Sandboxing means you cannot directly write outside your app's folder. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Thank you Joride for mentioning dispatch_async(), I didn't know about it and tried to use it. I have implemented it in my Answer to this question, is it fine? I also used the code to get the file directory to save the list to but found out it gave out the directory starting with file:/// which couldn't be used with writeToFile:atomically: method, so I removed the part and it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the file back in `applicationDidBecomeActive` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, assuming the file was successfully created and it didn't somehow get deleted between the time you closed the app and restarted it, which shouldn't happen, unless you're cleaning the build container files explicitly, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed the issue.

The code now saves the file asynchronously in applicationDidEnterBackground as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    typedef void (^block)();
    block theBlock;

    theBlock = ^(){
        BOOL fileWritten = [self.viewController.tasks writeToFile:self.viewController.savedList atomically:YES];

        if(fileWritten)
        {
            NSLog(@"Saved");
        }
    };

    /* Saving file Asynchronorusly */
    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("QUEUE-1",DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, theBlock);

    }
```

and synchronously in applicationWillTerminate as follows:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    /* Saving file Synchronously */

    BOOL fileWritten = [self.viewController.tasks writeToFile:self.viewController.savedList atomically:YES];

    if(fileWritten)
    {
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }
}
```

Those who pointed out that I didn't have any retrieval code, I am sorry I forgot to mention it. It loads the .plist in applicationDidFinishLaunching as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [self.viewController myButton:nil];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    NSURL *fileDirectory = self.viewController.applicationDocumentsDirectory;

    NSMutableString *filePath = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[fileDirectory absoluteString]];
    [filePath appendString:@"list.plist"];
    filePath = (NSMutableString *)[filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file:///" withString:@""];

    self.viewController.savedList = filePath;

    if([[NSFileManager alloc] fileExistsAtPath:self.viewController.savedList])
    {
        self.viewController.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.viewController.savedList];
        NSLog(@"DATA READ: %@", self.viewController.tasks);
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

So, now the app works as expected. Thank you guys.

Comment: This looks like a working implementation, so great work! Note that when you are still loading the data synchronously on the main thread, so when there is a big file to be loaded, the app will be unresponsive for the time the loading takes place. You could load the data in the background, just like saving, and then assigning the tasks-array to the viewController by dispatching again from within your block onto the main-queue (dispatch_get_mainqueue()). Remember that didFinishLauchingWithOptions: is only called from a 'cold' launch, not when it comes back to the foreground.